# jquery bounce effect not working with floating elements

Tags: jquery, css, css-float, bounce

I am using a  which has  links which are floated to left. Then when I am giving the bounce effect to the elements on click, when I am clicking them the bounce occurs but it shifts to the right of the container.

The phenomenon does not happen when I remove the float:left effect. I have been trying to find a replacement for the float property but unable to find any proper effect. 
This is my HTML code

```
<div id="menu"> 
        <ul>
        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lbDashboard" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"  onclick="lbDashboard_Click">Dashboard</asp:LinkButton></li>
        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lbFindHotfix" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" onclick="lbFindHotfix_Click">Search</asp:LinkButton></li>
        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lbHelpWiki" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" onclick="lbHelpWiki_Click">Help/Wiki</asp:LinkButton></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

and this is the CSS part

```
#menu {
padding-top:30px;
padding-right:30px;
margin: 0;
float: right;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}

#menu ul, #searchdropdown ul{
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
}

#mainlinks ul
{
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
}
#menu li, #mainlinks li, #searchdropdown li{
display: inline;
}

#menu a{
display: block;
float: left;
padding: 10px 10px;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
color: #616B4F;
}


#menu a:hover{
background: #9FAB87;
color: #FFFFFF;
border-top-left-radius:1em;
border-bottom-right-radius:1em;
}
```

This is my script code-

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {

        //Add bounce effect on Click of the DIV
        $('#lbDashboard').click(function () {
            $(this).effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 300);
        });

        $('#lbFindHotfix').click(function () {
            $(this).effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 300);
        });

        $('#lbHelpWiki').click(function () {
            $(this).effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 300);
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: I'm not experiencing what you're describing. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/s5tTx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you float the list items, not the links, and perform the bounce on the link?

```
#menu li, #mainlinks li, #searchdropdown li{
display: inline;
}

#menu li {
float: left;
padding: 10px 10px;
}

#menu a{
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
color: #616B4F;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For others searching for similar problems:

I had something like this:

```
<div>
  <a href="#">
    link
  </a>
  <div style="float:right;">
    Controls
  </div>
</div>
```

And I wanted the link to bounce a few times after a certain event.  But when it did, it messed up the display of the other inner div.

I switched the float to the other side, and now it works:

```
<div>
  <a href="#" style="float:left;">
    link
  </a>
  <div>
    Controls
  </div>
</div>
```